# Tomcat возвращает для ошибок HTML вместо JSON

Tags: java, http, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

**Задача:** есть REST сервис.
Любые ошибки с любым статусом (**4хх** ил **5хх**) он должен возвращать пользователю в виде **JSON**.

**В чем проблема:** для обработки ошибок и отправки ответов о них пользователю использую `@RestControllerAdvice`

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionResolver extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    //... часть кода пропущена

    @ExceptionHandler(value = MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handle(MyException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return ResponseEntity.
                status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).
                body(mapper.toExceptionResponse(e, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
    }

    //... Другие аналогичные обработчики ошибок

}
```

Есть контроллер, методы которого могут выбрасывать такие исключения:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myEntities")
public class ProductController {

    //... часть кода пропущена

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<MyEntityResponse> add(@RequestBody MyEntityRequest dto) {
        MyEntity myEntity = mapper.toMyEntityForAdd(dto); // -> Вот здесь может быть выбрашен MyException
        myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(mapper.toProductResponse(product));
    }

    //... часть кода пропущена
}
```

Исключение `MyException` выброшенное именно из метода add возвращается пользователю в виде **html** страницы с кодом ошибки **500**, а ожидается что будет возвращен **JSON** с кодом **400**.

При этом в логах появляется следующее:

`Servlet.service()` для сервлета `[dispatcherServlet]` в контексте с путем `[/nutritionManager]` выбросил исключение

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is MyException: some message
```

Я попробовал разобраться, в чем причина такого поведения.

**HTML** страница с кодом ошибки **500** возвращается когда исключения кидаются самим **Spring**-ом.

Т.е. иногда, исключение выброшенное из метода `add()` вместо обработки в `@RestControllerAdvice` приводит к какому-то внутреннему исключению `Spring`.

Но в чем причина такого поведения - я не могу понять.

Comment: Метод handle для MyException вызывается?

Comment: Да. Метод handle вызывается для MyException.

Comment: У меня все так (как надо) получается (на простом примере)... А если `mapper.toExceptionResponse(e, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` *ТОЖЕ* чегонибудь выбрасывает (не `MyException`/без `Advice`a)??

Comment: Проверял. Но в логах видно, что все исключения летят именно из mapper.toMyEntityForAdd(dto);